# general question: working with wikidata and RDF

Tags: rdf, ontology, wikidata, wikidata-api

I have the following problem with editing ontology data.
i can query the data at wikidata per sparql, but they only return json files. 
These files only contain the s p o format.

But i want to extend this data with my own stuff (using owl from wikidata).  To do so I have to import them into some framework.

How can I do this and which tools do I need?

one example query:

```
SELECT ?subclass ?entity ?predicate WHERE {
  ?subclass (wdt:P279*) wd:Q2095.
  { ?entity ?predicate ?subclass. }
  UNION
  { ?subclass ?predicate ?entity. }
}
```

Comment: what kind of query do you send? If you want RDF data, you have to use a SPARQL `CONSTRUCT` query instead of `SELECT`

Comment: i added one example query

Comment: as I said, use a `CONSTRUCT` query instead and you will get proper RDF which you can use in whatever tool you use